# Can a service-layer object "service" a DAO-layer object?

Tags: java

Can a service-layer object "service" a DAO-layer object? Or is does this violate the integrity of a properly layered architecture?

e.g.,

```
class MyService {

}

class MyDao {
     private MyService myService;
}
```

Comment: Shouldnt it be the other way around? Tell don't ask as per http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TellDontAsk

Comment: Hvant read the DAO/DTO pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't do it.  DAOs ought to deal with databases; services manage other services and DAOs to fulfill their use cases.  It'd be better to have the service call the DAO and any other services that are required.

You risk a circular dependency with this arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of constructing services with DAO objects is to let the service encapsulate the DAO.

```
public class Service {
    private DAO dao;
}
public class DAO {}
```

This is useful e.g., to let a service encapsulate multiple DAO objects, or to provide additional logic such as transaction demarcation in the service.